# Problem with AC low voltage

Tags: hvac, low-voltage

My AC won’t turn on and the thermostat is not functioning properly. Voltage reading at the thermostat fluctuates between 7-9 volts. No low voltage at the contacter. I am still getting 240 at the contacter and the override button allows everything to turn on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you put a shelf or picture up and damaged the wire?

Comment: Is the control power supplied from a transformer in the AC condensing unit, or in the air handler/furnace?

Comment: The control power is coming from the air handler/furnace. 

No changes to anything near the wiring. Nothing hung up. 

Thank you

Comment: Are there batteries in the remote? I have seen cases where the batteries drew down the supply voltage from the transformer to the point the thermostat could not change states. Verify it’s not the thermostat dragging down the control voltage if there was no voltage I would look at the transformer or fuse on the control board. Since there is voltage it is the thermostat or contactor coil (you have the 240 and bypass works so it’s the contactor itself or the thermostat in most cases).

Comment: Check voltage between R and **every** other terminal (W, G, Y at the least).

Comment: Batteries are fresh in the thermostat. 

Voltage between R and the others is the same, 5-7 volts and fluctuates while the multimeter is on it.

Comment: @David -- what make and model is your furnace/air-handler/indoor unit? What voltage do you measure between R and C at the furnace board with a) the thermostat wired up and b) the thermostat disconnected?